# Task.WhenAll behaves different if Task.Delay used

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I stumbled on something I can't really wrap my head around.

**Example Code**

Consider this example code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Example(false)
        .ConfigureAwait(false)
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
      
    Console.ReadLine();

}
    
public static async Task Example(bool pause)
{
    List<int> items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    foreach(var item in items) {
        await ProcessItem(item, pause);
    }

    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("using normal foreach: " + (end - start));
    
    var tasks = items.Select(x => ProcessItem(x, pause));

    start = DateTime.Now;

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    
    end = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("using Task.WhenAll " + (end - start));
}

public static async Task ProcessItem(int item, bool pause)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{item}]: invoked at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));

    if (pause) {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    int x = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1 * 1000000; i++) {
        x = await Calculate(i);
    }
   
}

public static async Task<int> Calculate(int item)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(item + 5);
}
```

In the `Example` method I simply call the `ProcessItem` method, at first with a normal foreach and then with `Task.WhenAll`.

`ProcessItem` takes some number and a flag indicating whether `await.TaskDelay(1)` should be invoked, more on that later. Besides that, all it does it simulate some longer running code + a call to a third awaitable method (`Calculate`).

**Result**

The result when running the code is

```
[0]: invoked at 01:19:17.417
[1]: invoked at 01:19:17.898
[2]: invoked at 01:19:18.330
[3]: invoked at 01:19:18.782
[4]: invoked at 01:19:19.118
[5]: invoked at 01:19:19.472
[6]: invoked at 01:19:19.716
[7]: invoked at 01:19:19.961
[8]: invoked at 01:19:20.179
[9]: invoked at 01:19:20.402
using normal foreach: 00:00:03.2314927

[0]: invoked at 01:19:20.639
[1]: invoked at 01:19:20.887
[2]: invoked at 01:19:21.178
[3]: invoked at 01:19:21.440
[4]: invoked at 01:19:21.670
[5]: invoked at 01:19:21.954
[6]: invoked at 01:19:22.390
[7]: invoked at 01:19:22.880
[8]: invoked at 01:19:23.218
[9]: invoked at 01:19:23.449
using Task.WhenAll 00:00:03.0749655
```

The normal loop and `Task.WhenAll` take about the same time for the execution, looks like both versions work sequentially because in both cases there's always some delay between the outputs.

Now let's make things weird.
If I pass `true` instead of `false` to `Example`, the method now invokes `await.TaskDelay(1)`, resulting in a different execution as you can see in the result.

```
[0]: invoked at 01:22:17.047
[1]: invoked at 01:22:17.521
[2]: invoked at 01:22:17.886
[3]: invoked at 01:22:18.337
[4]: invoked at 01:22:18.735
[5]: invoked at 01:22:19.024
[6]: invoked at 01:22:19.262
[7]: invoked at 01:22:19.500
[8]: invoked at 01:22:19.731
[9]: invoked at 01:22:19.992
using normal foreach: 00:00:03.2050316
[0]: invoked at 01:22:20.240
[1]: invoked at 01:22:20.241
[2]: invoked at 01:22:20.241
[3]: invoked at 01:22:20.241
[4]: invoked at 01:22:20.242
[5]: invoked at 01:22:20.242
[6]: invoked at 01:22:20.242
[7]: invoked at 01:22:20.243
[8]: invoked at 01:22:20.243
[9]: invoked at 01:22:20.244
using Task.WhenAll 00:00:01.4674985
```

As you can see, the normal loop works as usual but apparently `Task.WhenAll` now decides to call the `ProcessItem` method for all items at the same time - whereas before, one item after the other was being processed.

**Questions**

Why does executing `await Task.Delay(1)` make such a huge difference?

Why doesn't the first version (where `await Task.Delay(1)` wasn't being called) call the `ProcessItem` for all items at around the same time?

It seems like I'm missing something here. I've tested the code with .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.7.2 - same results.

Comment: The `Task.Delay` call is the only place in your code where things actually are processed async. Without it everything runs sequentially.

Comment: `Task.FromResult` doesn't magically make a CPU-bound operation async

Comment: Why is `var tasks = items.Select(x => ProcessItem(x, pause));` before the `start = DateTime.Now;` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have `await MyAsyncMethod()`, that MyAsyncMethod returns a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) that may or may not be in an IsCompleted state. And the execution of the rest of the containing method depends on that state.

- When the task is "completed", execution continues *synchronously*.
- When the task is not yet completed, the containing async method *returns* an **incomplete** task. The rest of the containing method will be executed whenever this task completes.

In your `Calculate` method, you are returning `Task.FromResult`, which is a completed task. Task.Delay however is not completed until the timeout passes, so you immediately get an incomplete Task.

So with `pause==false`, your methods run in effect synchronously and all have completed when the foreach is finished, leaving nothing for Task.WhenAll to wait on.

With `pause==true`, the `ProcessItem` method returns an incomplete task *as soon as* the Delay is hit. So the several invocations of this method are started rapidly (you see the Console.WriteLine output close together in time) and only after the delays have expired, is the rest executed - in the `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, understood that. In my real-world case I do have some sort of 'pause' switch when calling something external that is not yet fully asynchronous. I think the problem will solve itself once that changes.